# Use a single GPIO pin to activate both LED and buzzer

Tags: gpio, led

Is this possible?  My question yesterday led me to this circuit using an NPN transistor for the buzzer:  https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits#Output_circuits

It's actually more like this: http://www.sunrom.com/media/content/598/drv.jpg with the diode.  and using a 3.3 V power supply (since that what my buzzer takes)

My question is, how do I modify my circuit to light up my green led simultaneously with my buzzer?  I tried just moving the input wire to the LED's gpio pin instead of the dedicated buzzer pin and the light stopped working when the buzzer sounded.

Thanks for all the help sofar guys

Comment: What does "I tried just moving the input wire to the LED's gpio pin instead of the dedicated buzzer pin" mean? We can't read your mind, you need to describe what you are doing.

Comment: It means I'm an idiot that knows nothing about circuitry.  I added the led property in serial it worked.  Aka now I have: GPIO -> LED -> 100R -> NPN base -> 1k R -> ground.  The light is a bit dimmer, but I can live with that

Comment: My real question I suppose is, is the above a "safe" thing to do electonically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the LED, in series with its current limiting resistor from 5V or 3.3V to the transistor Collector,

Vcc -> LED -> 100R -> C

This assumes you have your circuit wired as in [Output Circuits](https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits#Output_circuits)

Comment: So you're saying instead of driving the LED with the gpio pin I should connect its negative terminal to the c pin of my resistor?  I'm very dense on this stuff, a quick diagram sketch (that modifies http://www.sunrom.com/media/content/598/drv.jpg) may help

Comment: Here's what I ended up going with (or similair) http://www.gadgetronicx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/continuity-tester.jpg